# MyPy: 'incompatible type' for virtual class inheritance

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

### Demo code

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(metaclass = ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return (
            hasattr(subclass, 'x')
        )

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Concrete:
    x: float = 1.0

class Application:
    def __init__(self, obj: Base) -> None:
        print(obj.x)

ob = Concrete() 
app = Application(ob)

print(issubclass(Concrete, Base))
print(isinstance(Concrete, Base))
print(type(ob))
print(Concrete.__mro__)
```

`python test_typing.py` returns:

```
1.0
True
False
<class '__main__.Concrete'>
(<class '__main__.Concrete'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and `mypy test_typing.py` returns:

```
test_typing.py:30: error: Argument 1 to "Application" has incompatible type "Concrete"; expected "Base"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source
```

But if i change the line `class Concrete:` to `class Concrete(Base):`, i get for
`python test_typing.py` this:

```
1.0
True
False
<class '__main__.Concrete'>
(<class '__main__.Concrete'>, <class '__main__.Base'>, <class 'object'>)
```

and for `mypy test_typing.py` this:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

If i add to my code this:

```
reveal_type(Concrete)
reveal_type(Base)
```

i get in both cases the same results for it from `mypy test_typing.py`:

```
test_typing.py:37: note: Revealed type is "def () -> vmc.test_typing.Concrete"
test_typing.py:38: note: Revealed type is "def () -> vmc.test_typing.Base"
```

### Conclusion

Seems obvious, that MyPi have some problems with virtual base classes but non-virtual inheritance seems working as expected.

### Question

How works MyPy's type estimation in these cases?
Is there an workaround?

### 2nd Demo code

Using `Protocol` pattern:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class Base(Protocol):
    @property
    def x(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, x: float) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    """
    @classmethod
    def test(self) -> None:
        pass
    """

class Concrete:
    x: float = 1.0

class Application:
    def __init__(self, obj: Base) -> None:
        pass

ob = Concrete() 
app = Application(ob)
```

### Pros

- Working with `mypy`: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`
- Working with `isinstance(Concrete, Base)` : `True`

### Cons

- Not working with `issubclass(Concrete, Base)`: `TypeError: Protocols with non-method members don't support issubclass()`
- Not checking the `__init__` method signatures: `__init__(self, x: float) -> None` vs. `__init__(self) -> None` (Why returns `inspect.signature()` the strings `(self, *args, **kwargs)` and `(self, /, *args, **kwargs)` here? With `class Base:` instead of `class Base(Protocol):` i get `(self, x: float) -> None` and `(self, /, *args, **kwargs)`)
- ignoring the difference between `@abstractmethod` and `@classmethod` (treats ANY method as abstract)

### 3rd Demo code

This time just an more complex example of the 1st code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from inspect import signature

class Base(metaclass = ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return (
            hasattr(subclass, 'x') and
            (signature(subclass.__init__) == signature(cls.__init__))
        )

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, x: float) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def test(self) -> None:
        pass

class Concrete:
    x: float = 1.0

    def __init__(self, x: float) -> None:
        pass

class Application:
    def __init__(self, obj: Base) -> None:
        pass

ob = Concrete(1.0) 
app = Application(ob)
```

### Pros

- Working with `issubclass(Concrete, Base)`: `True`
- Working with `isinstance(Concrete, Base)`: `False`
- Method signature check also for `__init__`.

### Cons

- Not working with MyPy:

  ```
  test_typing.py:42: error: Argument 1 to "Application" has incompatible type "Concrete"; expected "Base"
  Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
  ```

### 4th Demo code

In some circumstances the following code might be an possible solution.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable
from dataclasses import dataclass

@runtime_checkable
class Rotation(Protocol):
    @property
    def x(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @property
    def y(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def z(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def w(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

@dataclass
class Quaternion:
    x: float = 0.0
    y: float = 0.0
    z: float = 0.0
    w: float = 1.0

    def conjugate(self) -> 'Quaternion':
        return type(self)(
            x = -self.x,
            y = -self.y,
            z = -self.z,
            w = self.w
        )

class Application:
    def __init__(self, rot: Rotation) -> None:
        print(rot)

q = Quaternion(0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0)
app = Application(q.conjugate())
```

### Pros:

- Auto-generated `__init__` method because of `@dataclass` usage. here: `(self, x: float = 0.0, y: float = 0.0, z: float = 0.0, w: float = 1.0) -> None`
- Works with `isinstance()`: `True`
- Works with mypy: `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`

### Cons:

- You need to hope, that the next developer uses `@dataclass` along with implementing your interface..
- Not usable for `__init__` methods, that are not only taken class attributes.

**Tipp:** If an forced `__init__` method is not required and only want to take care of the attributes, then just omit `@dataclass`.

### 5th Demo code

Updated the 4th code to provide more safety, but without implicit `__init__` method:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from abc import abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class Rotation(Protocol):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def y(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def z(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def w(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Quaternion:
    _x: float = 0.0
    _y: float = 0.0
    _z: float = 0.0
    _w: float = 1.0

    @property
    def x(self) -> float:
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self) -> float:
        return self._y

    @property
    def z(self) -> float:
        return self._z

    @property
    def w(self) -> float:
        return self._w

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, z: float, w: float) -> None:
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)
        self._z = float(z)
        self._w = float(w)

    def conjugate(self) -> 'Quaternion':
        return type(self)(
            x = -self.x,
            y = -self.y,
            z = -self.z,
            w = self.w
        )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ", ".join(
            (
                str(self._x),
                str(self._y),
                str(self._z),
                str(self._w)
            )
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        cls = self.__class__
        module = cls.__module__
        return f"{module + '.' if module != '__main__' else ''}{cls.__qualname__}({str(self)})"

class Application:
    def __init__(self, rot: Rotation) -> None:
        print(rot)

q = Quaternion(0.7, 0.0, 0.7, 0.0)
app = Application(q.conjugate())
```

### Current conclusion

The `Protocol` way is unstable.
But the `Metaclass` way is not checkable, because it's not working with MyPy (because it's not static).

### Updated question

Are there any alternative solutions to achieve some type of **Interfaces** (without `class Concrete(Base)`) AND make it type-safe (checkable)?

Comment: `mypy` does *static* type checking. The fact that `Base.__subclasshook__` returns `True` for `Concrete` is a *dynamic* (i.e., runtime) property of `Base.` Take a look at `typing.Protocol` instead. (I don't recall if it works with non-method attributes, though.)

Comment: @chepner Do you mean this: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#simple-user-defined-protocols ?
okay, will test it.
Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, you're looking for `Protocol`. mypy doesn't run Python code to figure out subclass relationships, because if it did it would run up against the halting problem, so it's necessarily conservative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Result

After running some tests and more research i am sure, that the actual problem is the behaviour of `Protocol` to silently overwrite the defined `__init__` method.

### Conclusion

Seems logical, since Protocols are not intended to be initiated.
But sometimes it's required to define an `__init__` method,
because in my opinion `__init__` methods are also part of the interface of classes and it's objects.

### Solution

I found an existing issue about this problem, that seems to confirm my point of view: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88970

Fortunately it's already fixed:
https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/5f2abae61ec69264b835dcabe2cdabe57b9a990e

But unfortunately, this fix will only be part of Python 3.11 and above.

Currenty is Python 3.10.5 available.

**WARNING:** Like mentioned in the issue, some static type checkers might behave different in this case. **MyPy** just ignores the missing `__init__` method (tested it, confirmed) BUT **Pyright** seems to detect and report the missing `__init__` method (not tested by me).